# Prove $L^p$ is reflexive for $1<p<\infty$ by using Riesz representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, reflexive-space

By definition, $X$ is reflexive if canonical injection $J:E \to E^{**}$ is surjective, where 
$\langle Jx,f\rangle_{E^{**},E^*}=\langle f,x\rangle_{E^*,E},~\forall x \in E,~\forall f \in E^*.$ In order to show $E$ is reflexive, it is not enough to show the existence of linear surjective isometry from $E$ to $E^{**}$.

I'd like to know if it is possible to show $L^p$ is reflexive for $1<p<\infty$ by using Riesz representation theorem. 
By Riesz representation theorem, $(L^p)^* =L^{p'}$, where $1/p+1/p'=1.$

**Usually people say "since $(L^p)^{**} =(L^{p'})^*=L^p$, $L^p$ is reflexive**"

It seems right, but I'd like to prove it in detail. Would you give me any comment for this question? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of detail would you like to see? The one line proof is detailed enough, given Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: @Cave Johnson I'd like to show $L^p$ is reflexive by showing the canonical injection is surjective. Is it enough by the one line proof?

Comment: If you write explicitly the isomorphism from $(L^{p})^{*}$ to $L^{p'}$ and the isomorphism from $(L^{p'})^{*}$ to $L^{p}$ , the inverse of their composition becomes exactly the canonical embedding of $L^{p}$ onto $(L^{p})^{**}$. No tricks needed.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy I don't get it. Sorry. Do we need adjoint operator?Could you write it in detail by answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the isomorphism $(L^p)^* = L^{p'}$ is given by

$$\Phi_p : L^{p'}\to  (L^p)^*,\ \  \Phi_p (f) (g) = \int_X fg d\mu.$$

Now we check that the canonical homomorphism is isomorphism: indeed, for all $f\in L^p$ and $\ell \in (L^p)^*$,

$$\begin{split}
 J (f) (\ell) &= \ell (f) \\
&= (\Phi_p\Phi_p^{-1})(\ell) (f) \\
&= \int_X \Phi_p^{-1}(\ell) f d\mu \\
&=\int_X f \Phi_p^{-1}(\ell) d\mu \\
&= \Phi_{p'} (f) (\Phi^{-1}_p \ell) \\
&= ((\Phi_p^{-1})^*\circ \Phi_{p'} (f))(\ell).
\end{split}$$

So $J(f) = (\Phi_p^{-1})^*\circ \Phi_{p'}(f)$ and thus $J$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: What is $Phi_p^{-1})^*$?

Comment: That's the adjoint operator of $\Phi_p^{-1}$. @0876